# How to set up permalinks with variables in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, permalinks

I'm trying to setup jekyll so that it will automatically create permalinks for new posts but it's not working.

What I did is setting a variable in the _config.yml like this:

```
permalink: /:title/
```

then, in a loop of post previews on the homepage I created a link like this:

```
<a href="{{ post.permalink }}">Read More</a>
```

Expecting the output to be something like.

```
<a href="/I-am-the-title-of-this-post">Read More</a>
```

and instead I'm getting this:

```
<a href="/:title/">Read More</a>
```

which if I click gives a 404 Not Found error.

What am I doing wrong?

For more info [here](https://github.com/matteocarpi/julia/tree/develop) is the github repo.

Thanks!

Matteo

Comment: Use `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}`.

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Jaquel suggested I solved by using

```
{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}
```